# R in Ubuntu Server 14.04 - Writing file to a samba sharing in which a directory is protected by user/pass

Tags: r, file, ubuntu, rstudio, samba

I was wondering if writing to a protected samba directory, to a internal directory with another user/pass could be possible. I have been searching for an R package with these capabilities but I haven't found it yet. Now I'm using the `write()` function. In the documentation for this function, it says:

> Arguments:
>
> x : The data to be written out, usually an atomic vector.
>
> file : A connection, or a character string naming the file to write to. If "", print to the standard output connection. If it is "|cmd", the output is piped to the command given by ‘cmd’.

I don't understand if the attribute "file" when writing "|cmd" launches the Terminal in Ubuntu server or something, but I can't make it work

Hope you have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it can be done via a shell script in Ubuntu. The command is `write(somefile, file = "|sh shellWriteSamba.sh")`

Edit: The complete solution is in [R - write() a file to a SAMBA share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30051162/r-write-a-file-to-a-samba-share)