# R - write() a file to a SAMBA share

Tags: r, file, put, samba

I have a file loaded in R that I want to move to a samba share

It is something like

`write(some-file, file = "|smbclient -U user //ip password")`

It connects to the samba but then (I think) the output is "executed" in the `smb: \>` and I don't want the file to be executed, I don't know how to pass the file to the destination with a `put`function inside smbclient.

---

Edit: This is not the same problem as the first post. The first post is solved and answered by me. The point there was connecting to samba. Now I'm already connected to it but the write() function doesn't make a file, instead it pipes out the words separately. I just wanted to know how to make it create a file in a sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer by changing the philosophy:

First, I write the file locally, like

```
write(some-file, there)
```

Then I use the system() function to call smbclient and put the file already written

```
system("smbclient -U user //ip/dir password -c \"put some-file some-file\"")
```

My script is more complex and it's inside a Shiny app but in summary that's the solution